# How to insert new HTML code into existing page?

Tags: javascript

imagine you have simple page like this:

Hi everybody.
when you 
**click here**
new text will be inserted.

after click :

Hi everybody.
when you 
"ulala ... I am inserted text"
new text will be inserted.

1. is it possible to insert this text using PHP or Javascript?
2. If only javascript is appropriate may you provide a sample code?

thanx a lot

Comment: You want SO family to do code for you I think you have to do googling at very first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML:

```
<p>Hi everybody. when you <span id="mytext"><a href="javascript:EditText()">click here</a></span> new text will be inserted.</p>
```

Your Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function EditText() {
      document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = 'ulala... I am inserted text';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: inline js makes jon skeet cry.

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest with jQuery, but you can use Javascript DOM methods for that.

To make a link happen something, use `onClick="js_something()"`. And to insert text use `$('#id').text('new text')`.

PHP comes only into play if that new text is to be retrieved from a server resource (url). If so use AJAX, or simply `.load(".../get_text.php")` in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript try following:

```
function fun(){
document.getElementById("text_area").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text_area").value + "New str";
}
```

call `fun()` on `onclick` of "Click here" which has an id `text_area` and could be `div` or `span` or `input` or `textarea` any other html  tag wherever you wanna add new String.

Hope this helps.